# Facebook graph API - get custom profile picture size

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the logged in user's profile picture for a canvas app, but I would like to have it in a specific size.

Is this possible and, if so, how?

Currently I'm using the following:

```
graph.facebook.com/{user's FB ID}/picture?type=square
```

This gives me a 50px by 50px image. There are also options to use type=normal and type=large to give large image size, but these are not square images, and also not the exact size I am looking for.

To be specific, is there a way to get a member's profile picture in size 80px by 80px directly from Facebook, without downloading a larger image and downsizing/cropping on my end?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use width/height as parameter:

```
graph.facebook.com/{user's FB ID}/picture?width=100&height=100
```

Just keep in mind that you may not get exact sizes, but very close ones.

Comment: this sadly doesn't work with facebook users who never had their profile image set. It might be a facebook bug though... see example - https://graph.facebook.com/1546686145549786/picture?type=large&width=200&height=200

Comment: Well apparently we have users in our website who do not have their avatar set. I filed a bug report to Facebook on the matter. It might help if we all file this bug report :)

Comment: filing multiple bug reports is not a good idea, that´s just more work for facebook. better post your report as comment in here so we can subscribe.

Comment: well Facebook have no system to track bugs (as far as I know), it's very primitive. they ask to click on top right-most arrow and on the button you have a button which opens a dialog box and you just file the report and that's it. there are no ticket, comments or stars.

Comment: actually, they do have a very good bug tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: well seems google doesn't find that page for the most basic search term "**facebook report bug**". that is a bug by itself.

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the number of requests you can make to the API for the profile pictures?

Answer (score 12):

Getting a bigger facebook profile picture via [facebook php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk), this worked for me:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=picture.width(400).height(400)', getenv('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN'));
```

in 2019!

Comment: It works. Is there any way to get  2 picture of different size

Comment: This is the updated answer.. everything else crashes on versions 10+

Answer (score 2):

https://graph.facebook.com/[[[[insertusersfbid]]]]/picture?type=large 
 Is what i fall back to... 
https://graph.facebook.com/[[[[insertusersfbid]]]]/picture?width=2000&height=2000
 Is when i want to muck with the image.
If the user does not have an uploaded profilepicture; now fb returns the gender based default pic...
I hope this helps someone else :)